# How to change the border color of combo box by c# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have style of combobox and i want to change Border Brush Color of combo box by c# code ,here  the xaml code of combo box border brush

```
 <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Border"
          BorderBrush="#e3e9ef" 
          CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1, 1, 1, 1" 
          Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush}" />
```

I set name of border and i want to change it by code here is my c# code

```
 Border  myBorder1 = new Border();
              myBorder1.FindName("Border");
              myBorder1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
```

the problem is the code it's bot working can any one help me for change the border color please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your border name you can set the color without creating a new Border   like this,

**XAML**

```
 <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="BorderSample"
          BorderBrush="#e3e9ef" 
          CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1, 1, 1, 1" 
          Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush}" />
```

**C#**

```
BorderSample.BorderBrush = Brushes.SlateBlue;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the XAML file you could remove the BorderBrush property.

```
 <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="BorderSample" 
      CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1, 1, 1, 1" 
      Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBackgroundBrush}" />
```

and in the .cs file you could write.

```
borderSample.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(new Color { R = 0xe3, G = 0xe9, B = 0xef, A = byte.MaxValue });
```